# WinForms Poker (complete project)

Tags: c#, beginner, object-oriented, winforms, playing-cards

I have quite huge question/favor to ask but I hope I can get some useful answers. This is my first complete project, I'm still learning C#, my first programming language.

I'm afraid that there will be a lot of things that people won't probably understand but you can also check some of my other questions they include fairly enough information about some of my code.

The main thing about the project is obviously the way I determine the play hand. Here's a link to a little bit more detailed explanation of why I'm using modulus and divide operator to check the current card type/suit : [Defining what combination the user have in Poker](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/121973/defining-what-combination-the-user-have-in-poker)

How I keep things up-to date: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/121942/update-method-using-timer-in-winforms-poker-app

How I actually check if the player has a specific combination: [Strategy pattern using an abstract class and an interface](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/122102/strategy-pattern-using-an-abstract-class-and-an-interface)

There are a few more question in my user profile which you can try using to get a better understanding of what's going on. Any improvements are welcomed as well as any suggestion that I can implement.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Poker.Achievements;
using Poker.Combinations;
using Poker.Users;
using Flush = Poker.Achievements.Flush;
using FourOfAKind = Poker.Achievements.FourOfAKind;
using FullHouse = Poker.Achievements.FullHouse;
using RoyalFlush = Poker.Achievements.RoyalFlush;
using Straight = Poker.Achievements.Straight;
using StraightFlush = Poker.Achievements.StraightFlush;


namespace Poker
{
    public partial class MainPoker : Form
    {
        public enum TableCards
        {
            FirstCard = 12,
            SecondCard = 13,
            ThirdCard = 14,
            FourthCard = 15,
            FifthCard = 16
        }

        #region Variables

        public static Classic Classic = new Classic();
        public static RoyalFlush RoyalFlushAchievement = new RoyalFlush(1, new Tuple<string, int?>("Royal Card Pack", 100000));

        public static StraightFlush StraightFlushAchievement = new StraightFlush(1,
            new Tuple<string, int?>("Bicycle Card Back", 50000));

        public static FourOfAKind FourOfAKindAchievement = new FourOfAKind(1, new Tuple<string, int?>("Angel Card Back", 35000));
        public static FullHouse FullHouseAchievement = new FullHouse(3, new Tuple<string, int?>("Awesome Card Back", 30000));
        public static Flush FlushAchievement = new Flush(5, new Tuple<string, int?>("Water Card Back", 20000));
        public static Straight StraightAchievement = new Straight(5, new Tuple<string, int?>("Twisted Card Back", 15000));
        public static MoneyFirst MoneyFirstAchievement = new MoneyFirst(500000, new Tuple<string, int?>("Rich Card Back", null));

        public static MoneySecond MoneySecondAchievement = new MoneySecond(2000000,
            new Tuple<string, int?>("Mansion Card Back", null));

        public static PlayedHands PlayedHandsAchievement = new PlayedHands(100, new Tuple<string, int?>("Blue Card Pack", null));

        public static Player Player = new Player(Properties.Settings.Default.StartingChips, new Point(560, 470));

        public static Bot Bot1 = new Bot(10000, AnchorStyles.Left, "Bot 1", 2, (int)UsersProperties.CUser.Bot1,
            new Point(15, 420), false, new Tuple<int?, int>(Player.Chips, 6));

        public static Bot Bot2 = new Bot(10000, AnchorStyles.Left, "Bot 2", 4, (int)UsersProperties.CUser.Bot2,
            new Point(75, 65), true, new Tuple<int?, int>(Player.Chips, 6));

        public static Bot Bot3 = new Bot(10000, AnchorStyles.Left, "Bot 3", 6, (int)UsersProperties.CUser.Bot3,
            new Point(590, 25), true, new Tuple<int?, int>(Player.Chips, 6));

        public static Bot Bot4 = new Bot(10000, AnchorStyles.Left, "Bot 4", 8, (int)UsersProperties.CUser.Bot4,
            new Point(1115, 65), true, new Tuple<int?, int>(Player.Chips, 6));

        public static Bot Bot5 = new Bot(10000, AnchorStyles.Left, "Bot 5", 10, (int)UsersProperties.CUser.Bot5,
            new Point(1160, 420), false, new Tuple<int?, int>(Player.Chips, 6));

        private Hand _sorted;
        private readonly Help _help = new Help();

        public static int ThinkTime { get; set; } = Properties.Settings.Default.ThinkingTime;

        public static int[] AllAchievements { get; set; } = {
            Properties.Settings.Default.GetStraight,
            Properties.Settings.Default.GetFlush,
            Properties.Settings.Default.GetFullHouse,
            Properties.Settings.Default.GetFourOfAKind,
            Properties.Settings.Default.GetStraightFlush,
            Properties.Settings.Default.GetRoyalFlush,
            Properties.Settings.Default.GetMoneyF,
            Properties.Settings.Default.GetMoneyS,
            Properties.Settings.Default.GetPlayedHands,
        };
        public static bool Raising { get; set; }
        public static int AchivementMoney { get; set; }
        public static int AchivementHands { get; set; }
        public static int Bb { get; set; } = 500;
        public static int Sb { get; set; } = 250;
        public static int Call { get; set; } = 500;
        public static int Raise { get; set; }
        public static int Rounds { get; set; }
        public static int TempCall { get; set; }
        public int Folds { get; set; }
        public int WonHands { get; set; }
        public int LostHands { get; set; }
        public int PlayedHands1 { get; set; }

        public static string[] StatusLabels { get; } = new string[6];
        public static string[] ChipsTextBoxes { get; } = new string[6];
        public static string[] UsernameLabels { get; } = new string[6];

        public static bool[] AllAchievementsBools { get; set; } = {
            Properties.Settings.Default.GetStraight >= StraightAchievement.Requirement,
            Properties.Settings.Default.GetFlush >= FlushAchievement.Requirement,
            Properties.Settings.Default.GetFullHouse >= FullHouseAchievement.Requirement,
            Properties.Settings.Default.GetFourOfAKind >= FourOfAKindAchievement.Requirement,
            Properties.Settings.Default.GetStraightFlush >= StraightFlushAchievement.Requirement,
            Properties.Settings.Default.GetRoyalFlush >= RoyalFlushAchievement.Requirement,
            Properties.Settings.Default.GetMoneyF >= MoneyFirstAchievement.Requirement,
            Properties.Settings.Default.GetMoneyS >= MoneySecondAchievement.Requirement,
            Properties.Settings.Default.GetPlayedHands >= PlayedHandsAchievement.Requirement,
        };

        public static List<Hand> Win { get; } = new List<Hand>();
        public static string GetCards { get; set; } = @"Assets\Cards\Pack_Classic";
        public static string GetBack { get; set; } = @"Assets\Back\Back_Classic\Back_Classic.png";

        public static Timer Timer { get; set; } = new Timer();
        public static Timer Updates { get; set; } = new Timer();

        private int _up = int.MaxValue,
            _i,
            _t = 30,
            _turnCount,
            _foldedPlayers = 5,
            _tableNumber = 12;

        private const int Flop = 1,
            Turn = 2,
            River = 3,
            End = 4;

        private static int _horizontal,
            _vertical,
            _correct,
            _newTurn,
            _winners;

        private static bool _restart;
        private static bool _addingChips;
        private bool _ifFormLoaded;
        private static bool dontRepeat;

        private static readonly string[] CombinationNames =
        {
            " High Card ",
            " Pair ",
            " Two Pair ",
            " Three of a Kind ",
            " Straight ",
            " Flush ",
            " Full House ",
            " Four of a Kind ",
            " Straight Flush ",
            " Royal Flush ! "
        };

        private List<bool> _turns = new List<bool>();
        private readonly List<UsersProperties> _users = new List<UsersProperties>();
        private readonly List<string> _addWinners = new List<string>();
        private static readonly int[] _reserve = new int[17];
        private static readonly Image[] Deck = new Image[52];
        private static readonly PictureBox[] Holder = new PictureBox[17];

        private static string[] _imgLocation = Directory.GetFiles(GetCards, "*.png", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        private static readonly List<string> NewImgLocation = new List<string>();

//                private static string[] _imgLocation ={
//                    @"Assets\Cards\Pack_Classic\51.png",@"Assets\Cards\Pack_Classic\52.png",
//                    @"Assets\Cards\Pack_Classic\4.png",@"Assets\Cards\Pack_Classic\20.png",
//                    @"Assets\Cards\Pack_Classic\1.png",@"Assets\Cards\Pack_Classic\20.png",
//                    @"Assets\Cards\Pack_Classic\1.png",@"Assets\Cards\Pack_Classic\20.png",
//                    @"Assets\Cards\Pack_Classic\1.png",@"Assets\Cards\Pack_Classic\20.png",
//                    @"Assets\Cards\Pack_Classic\1.png",@"Assets\Cards\Pack_Classic\20.png",
//                
//                    @"Assets\Cards\Pack_Classic\1.png",
//                    @"Assets\Cards\Pack_Classic\18.png",@"Assets\Cards\Pack_Classic\32.png",
//                    @"Assets\Cards\Pack_Classic\10.png",@"Assets\Cards\Pack_Classic\23.png"};
        #endregion

    public MainPoker()
    {
        if (Player.Chips != null) AchivementMoney = (int)Player.Chips;
        AchivementHands = PlayedHands1;
        TempCall = Call;
        _users.Add(Player);
        _users.Add(Bot1);
        _users.Add(Bot2);
        _users.Add(Bot3);
        _users.Add(Bot4);
        _users.Add(Bot5);

        KeyPress +=
            Form1_KeyPress;
        Call = Bb;
        MaximizeBox = false;
        MinimizeBox = false;
        Updates.Start();
        InitializeComponent();
        PickNextBlind();
        Timer.Interval = (1000);
        Timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
        Updates.Interval = (100);
        Updates.Tick += Update_Tick;
        tbRaise.Text = (Bb * 2).ToString();
    }

    private async void MainPoker_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Player = (Player)SetControls(Player, pStatus, playerName, tbChips);
        Bot1 = (Bot)SetControls(Bot1, b1Status, bot1Name, tbBotChips1);
        Bot2 = (Bot)SetControls(Bot2, b2Status, bot2Name, tbBotChips2);
        Bot3 = (Bot)SetControls(Bot3, b3Status, bot3Name, tbBotChips3);
        Bot4 = (Bot)SetControls(Bot4, b4Status, bot4Name, tbBotChips4);
        Bot5 = (Bot)SetControls(Bot5, b5Status, bot5Name, tbBotChips5);

        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        {
            UsernameLabels[j] = _users[j].Name;
            _turns.Add(_users[j].FoldTurn);
            ChipsTextBoxes[j] = _users[j].ChipsTextBox.Text;
            StatusLabels[j] = _users[j].StatusLabel.Text;
        }

        Player = (Player)SetStatus(Player);
        Bot1 = (Bot)SetStatus(Bot1);
        Bot2 = (Bot)SetStatus(Bot2);
        Bot3 = (Bot)SetStatus(Bot3);
        Bot4 = (Bot)SetStatus(Bot4);
        Bot5 = (Bot)SetStatus(Bot5);

        _ifFormLoaded = true;

        await Shuffle();
        UpdateStatistics(Folds, PlayedHands1, LostHands, WonHands);

    }

    private string[] Shuffle(string[] input)
    {
        var random = new RngCrypto();
        for (_i = input.Length; _i > 0; _i--)
        {
            int j = random.Next(_i);
            string k = input[j];
            input[j] = input[_i - 1];
            input[_i - 1] = k;
        }
        return input;
    }
    private static string[] RemoveStrings(string[] input, IEnumerable<string> charsToRemove, int i)
    {
        foreach (string c in charsToRemove.Where(c => input != null))
        {
            input[i] = input[i].Replace(c, string.Empty);
        }
        return input;
    }

    private async Task Shuffle()
    {
        var refreshBackImage = new Bitmap(GetBack);
        SetPlayerStuff(false);
        MaximizeBox = false;
        MinimizeBox = false;
        bool check = false;
        _horizontal = Player.CardsLocation.X;
        _vertical = Player.CardsLocation.Y;
        _imgLocation = Shuffle(_imgLocation);
        string[] charsToRemove = { GetCards, ".png", @"\" };
        for (_i = 0; _i < 17; _i++)
        {
            if (dontRepeat) continue;
            if (Deck != null) Deck[_i] = Image.FromFile(_imgLocation[_i]);
            _imgLocation = RemoveStrings(_imgLocation, charsToRemove, _i);
            if (_reserve != null) _reserve[_i] = int.Parse(_imgLocation[_i]) - 1;
            if (Holder != null)
            {
                Holder[_i] = new PictureBox
                {
                    SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage,
                    Height = Settings.Height,
                    Width = Settings.Width,
                    Name = "pb" + _i
                };
                Controls.Add(Holder[_i]);
            }
            await Task.Delay(150);
            SetPlayers(Player, _i, ref check, refreshBackImage);
            SetPlayers(Bot1, _i, ref check, refreshBackImage);
            SetPlayers(Bot2, _i, ref check, refreshBackImage);
            SetPlayers(Bot3, _i, ref check, refreshBackImage);
            SetPlayers(Bot4, _i, ref check, refreshBackImage);
            SetPlayers(Bot5, _i, ref check, refreshBackImage);
            SetTable(_i, ref check, refreshBackImage);

            Bot1 = FoldedPlayer(Bot1);
            Bot2 = FoldedPlayer(Bot2);
            Bot3 = FoldedPlayer(Bot3);
            Bot4 = FoldedPlayer(Bot4);
            Bot5 = FoldedPlayer(Bot5);
            if (_i != (int)TableCards.FifthCard) continue;
            Ending();
            if (!_restart)
            {
                MaximizeBox = true;
                MinimizeBox = true;
                _restart = true;
            }
            await Turns();
            dontRepeat = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    private void Ending()
    {
        if (_foldedPlayers == 5)
        {
            var dialogResult = MessageBox.Show(@"Would You Like To Play Again ?",
                @"You Won , Congratulations ! ", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            switch (dialogResult)
            {
                case DialogResult.Yes:
                    Application.Restart();
                    break;
                case DialogResult.No:
                    Application.Exit();
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            _foldedPlayers = 5;
        }
    }
    private Bot FoldedPlayer(Bot user)
    {
        if (user.Chips <= 0)
        {
            user.FoldTurn = true;
            if (Holder != null)
            {
                Holder[user.RightCard].Visible = false;
                Holder[user.LeftCard].Visible = false;
            }
            user.UsernameLabel.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            user.FoldTurn = false;
            if (_i != user.LeftCard) return user;
            if (Holder[user.LeftCard] == null) return user;
            Holder[user.RightCard].Visible = true;
            Holder[user.LeftCard].Visible = true;
        }
        return user;
    }

    private void SetPlayers(UsersProperties user, int turn, ref bool check, Image refreshbackImage)
    {
        if (user.Chips <= 0) return;
        _foldedPlayers--;
        if (turn < user.RightCard || turn > user.LeftCard) return;
        if (Holder[user.RightCard].Tag != null)
        {
            Holder[user.LeftCard].Tag = _reserve[user.LeftCard];
        }
        Holder[user.RightCard].Tag = _reserve[user.RightCard];
        if (!check)
        {
            _horizontal = user.CardsLocation.X;
            _vertical = user.CardsLocation.Y;
        }
        check = true;
        Holder[turn].Anchor = user.CardsAnchor;
        Holder[turn].Image = refreshbackImage;
        if (turn < Bot1.RightCard)
        {
            Holder[turn].Image = Deck[_i];
        }
        Holder[turn].Location = new Point(_horizontal, _vertical);
        _horizontal += Holder[turn].Width;
        Holder[turn].Visible = true;
        Controls.Add(user.Panel);
        user.Panel.Location = user.PanelLocation;
        user.Panel.BackColor = Color.DarkBlue;
        user.Panel.Size = user.PanelSize;
        user.Panel.Visible = false;
        if (_i != user.LeftCard) return;
        check = false;
    }
    private void SetTable(int turn, ref bool check, Image refreshBackImage)
    {
        if (turn < _tableNumber) return;
        switch (_tableNumber)
        {
            case (int)TableCards.FirstCard:
                Holder[_tableNumber].Tag = _reserve[_tableNumber];
                break;
            default:
                if (turn > _tableNumber) Holder[turn].Tag = _reserve[turn];
                _tableNumber++;
                break;
        }
        if (!check)
        {
            _horizontal = 410;
            _vertical = 265;
        }
        check = true;
        if (Holder[turn] == null) return;
        Holder[turn].Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;
        Holder[turn].Image = refreshBackImage;
        //Holder[i].Image = Deck[i];
        Holder[turn].Location = new Point(_horizontal, _vertical);
        _horizontal += Holder[turn].Width + 20;
    }
    private static UsersProperties SetControls(UsersProperties user, Label status, Label username, TextBox chips)
    {
        if (chips != null)
        {
            chips.Text = RepetitiveVariables.Chips + user.Chips;
            status.Text = StatusLabels[user.EnumCasted];

            user.StatusLabel = status;
            user.ChipsTextBox = chips;
        }

        if (username == null) return user;
        username.Location = user.UsernameLabelLocation;
        username.Size = user.UsernameLabelSize;
        username.Text = user.Name;
        username.Visible = true;
        user.UsernameLabel = username;

        return user;
    }

    public static void ReplacePacks()
    {
        NewImgLocation.Clear();
        var previousBack = new Bitmap(GetBack);
        string helpPack = Properties.Settings.Default.CardPack;
        string helpBack = Properties.Settings.Default.CardBack;
        GetBack = helpBack;
        GetCards = helpPack;
        if (helpPack == null || helpBack == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (helpPack == "") return;
        string[] tempImgLocation = Directory.GetFiles(helpPack, "*.png", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        for (int j = 0; j < 17; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < tempImgLocation.Length; k++)
            {
                string[] charsToRemove = { helpPack, ".png", @"\" };
                tempImgLocation = RemoveStrings(tempImgLocation, charsToRemove, k);
                if (_imgLocation[j] == tempImgLocation[k])
                {
                    int tempInt = int.Parse(tempImgLocation[k]);
                    NewImgLocation.Add($@"{helpPack}\{tempInt}.png");
                    if (Help.AreEqual((Bitmap)Holder[j].Image, previousBack))
                    {
                        Holder[j].Image = new Bitmap(helpBack);
                        GetBack = Properties.Settings.Default.CardBack;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Holder[j].Image = new Bitmap(NewImgLocation[j]);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(@"An unexpected error has occured !" + ex.Message);
                            Application.Exit();
                        }
                    }
                    if (Deck != null) Deck[j] = new Bitmap(NewImgLocation[j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public static void ReplaceBacks()
    {
        var previousBack = new Bitmap(GetBack);
        string helpBack = Properties.Settings.Default.CardBack;
        GetBack = helpBack;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(helpBack)) return;
        for (int j = 0; j < 17; j++)
        {
            if (!Help.AreEqual((Bitmap)Holder[j].Image, previousBack)) continue;
            Holder[j].Image = new Bitmap(helpBack);
            GetBack = Properties.Settings.Default.CardBack;
        }
    }

    private static List<bool> ReturnTurns()
    {
        return new List<bool>
        {
            Player.FoldTurn,
            Bot1.FoldTurn,
            Bot2.FoldTurn,
            Bot3.FoldTurn,
            Bot4.FoldTurn,
            Bot5.FoldTurn
        };
    }
    private void SetPlayerStuff(bool enableOrDisable)
    {
        if (enableOrDisable)
        {
            pbTimer.Value = 1000;
            _t = 30;
            Timer.Enabled = true;
        }
        else Timer.Enabled = false;

        pbTimer.Visible = enableOrDisable;
        bRaise.Enabled = enableOrDisable;
        bCall.Enabled = enableOrDisable;
        bRaise.Enabled = enableOrDisable;
        bRaise.Enabled = enableOrDisable;
        bFold.Enabled = enableOrDisable;
    }

    private async Task Turns()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            _turns = ReturnTurns();
            GC.KeepAlive(Updates);
            if (!Player.FoldTurn && Player.Chips > 0)
            {
                if (Player.Turn)
                {
                    SetPlayerStuff(true);
                    Call -= Player.PreviousCall;
                    _up = int.MaxValue;
                    _turnCount++;
                    Bot1.Turn = true;
                    _restart = true;
                }
            }
            if (!Player.Turn)
            {
                await Flip(Player.EnumCasted);
            }
            if (Player.FoldTurn || !Player.Turn || Player.Chips <= 0)
            {
                Call = TempCall;
                if (StatusLabels[Player.EnumCasted].Contains(RepetitiveVariables.Fold))
                {
                    Bot1.Turn = true;
                }
                SetPlayerStuff(false);
                for (int j = 1; j < _users.Count; j++)
                {
                    _users[j] = await RotateTurns((Bot)_users[j]);
                }
                _restart = false;
            }
            if (!_restart)
            {
                continue;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    private async Task<Bot> RotateTurns(Bot user)
    {
        UsersProperties[] users = { Player, Bot1, Bot2, Bot3, Bot4, Bot5 };
        var userNext = new UsersProperties();
        for (int j = 0; j < users.Length; j++)
        {
            if (user == users[j])
            {
                userNext = j + 1 < users.Length ? users[j + 1] : users[0];
            }
        }
        if (!user.FoldTurn && user.Turn)
        {
            int previous = user.PreviousCall;
            Call -= user.PreviousCall;
            if (Properties.Settings.Default.ThinkCheck)
            {
                AutoCloseMsb.Show(user.Name + " Turn", "Turns", ThinkTime);
            }
            Combinations(user);
            user = (Bot)Ai(user, ref previous);
            await CheckTextBoxes();
            user.Turn = false;
            _turnCount++;
            userNext.Turn = true;
            CheckIfBlind(user, previous);
            Call = TempCall;
        }
        if (user.FoldTurn)
        {
            _turns = ReturnTurns();
            userNext.Turn = true;
        }
        await Flip(user.EnumCasted);
        return user;
    }
    private static void CheckIfBlind(UsersProperties user, int previousCall)
    {
        if (user.StatusLabel.Text.Contains(RepetitiveVariables.BigBlind))
        {
            user.PreviousCall = previousCall + Bb;
        }
        if (user.StatusLabel.Text.Contains(RepetitiveVariables.SmallBlind))
        {
            user.PreviousCall = previousCall + Sb;
        }
        if (!user.StatusLabel.Text.Contains(RepetitiveVariables.BigBlind) &&
            !user.StatusLabel.Text.Contains(RepetitiveVariables.SmallBlind))
        {
            user.PreviousCall = previousCall;
        }
    }
    private static UsersProperties PickNextBlindProperties(UsersProperties user, UsersProperties nextUser,
        int correctPass, string option)
    {
        if (nextUser != null) nextUser.Turn = true;
        user.Turn = false;
        if (option == RepetitiveVariables.BigBlind)
        {
            if (StatusLabels != null) StatusLabels[user.EnumCasted] = RepetitiveVariables.BigBlind + Bb;
            user.StatusLabel.Text = RepetitiveVariables.BigBlind + Bb;
            user.Chips -= Bb;
            user.PreviousCall = Bb;
        }
        else
        {
            if (StatusLabels != null) StatusLabels[user.EnumCasted] = RepetitiveVariables.SmallBlind + Sb;
            user.StatusLabel.Text = RepetitiveVariables.SmallBlind + Sb;
            user.Chips -= Sb;
            user.PreviousCall = Sb;
            _correct = correctPass;
        }
        _correct = correctPass;
        user = GetStatus(user);
        return user;
    }
    private void PickNextBlind()
    {
        switch (_newTurn)
        {
            case 0:
                Bot5 = (Bot)PickNextBlindProperties(Bot5, Player, Bot5.EnumCasted, RepetitiveVariables.BigBlind);
                Bot4 = (Bot)PickNextBlindProperties(Bot4, Player, Bot5.EnumCasted, RepetitiveVariables.SmallBlind);
                break;

            case 1:
                Player =
                    (Player)PickNextBlindProperties(Player, Bot1, Player.EnumCasted, RepetitiveVariables.BigBlind);
                Bot5 = (Bot)PickNextBlindProperties(Bot5, Bot1, Player.EnumCasted, RepetitiveVariables.SmallBlind);
                break;

            case 2:
                Bot1 = (Bot)PickNextBlindProperties(Bot1, Bot2, Bot1.EnumCasted, RepetitiveVariables.BigBlind);
                Player =
                    (Player)PickNextBlindProperties(Player, Bot2, Bot1.EnumCasted, RepetitiveVariables.SmallBlind);
                break;

            case 3:
                Bot2 = (Bot)PickNextBlindProperties(Bot2, Bot3, Bot2.EnumCasted, RepetitiveVariables.BigBlind);
                Bot1 = (Bot)PickNextBlindProperties(Bot1, Bot3, Bot2.EnumCasted, RepetitiveVariables.SmallBlind);
                break;

            case 4:
                Bot3 = (Bot)PickNextBlindProperties(Bot3, Bot4, Bot3.EnumCasted, RepetitiveVariables.BigBlind);
                Bot2 = (Bot)PickNextBlindProperties(Bot2, Bot4, Bot3.EnumCasted, RepetitiveVariables.SmallBlind);
                break;

            case 5:
                Bot4 = (Bot)PickNextBlindProperties(Bot4, Bot5, Bot4.EnumCasted, RepetitiveVariables.BigBlind);
                Bot3 = (Bot)PickNextBlindProperties(Bot3, Bot5, Bot4.EnumCasted, RepetitiveVariables.SmallBlind);
                break;
        }
        tbPot.Text = (Sb + Bb).ToString();
    }

    private void Combinations(UsersProperties user)
    {
        if (user.StatusLabel.Text.Contains(RepetitiveVariables.Fold)) return;

        for (_i = 0; _i < 16; _i++)
            if (_reserve[_i] == int.Parse(Holder[user.RightCard].Tag.ToString()) &&
                _reserve[_i + 1] == int.Parse(Holder[user.LeftCard].Tag.ToString()))
            {
                var combinationAnalyzers = new List<BaseCombinationAnalyzer>
                {
                    new HighCard(user, _reserve),
                    new PairFromTable(user, _reserve),
                    new PairInHand(user, _reserve),
                    new PairHandTable(user, _reserve),
                    new TwoPairFromTable(user, _reserve),
                    new TwoPairHandPairTablePair(user, _reserve),
                    new TwoPairHandTable(user, _reserve),
                    new TwoPairTwoDifferent(user, _reserve),
                    new ThreeOfAKind(user, _reserve),
                    new Combinations.Straight(user, _reserve),
                    new Combinations.Flush(user, _reserve),
                    new Combinations.FullHouse(user, _reserve),
                    new Combinations.FourOfAKind(user, _reserve),
                    new Combinations.StraightFlush(user, _reserve),
                    new Combinations.RoyalFlush(user, _reserve)
                };
                foreach (var combination in combinationAnalyzers)
                {
                    combination.Check(_reserve,user);
                }
                break;
            }
        if (Win.Count > 0)
            _sorted =
                Win.OrderByDescending(op => op.Current)
                    .ThenByDescending(op => op.Power)
                    .First();
    }

    private void Picking(int turn, int start, int segashenHod)
    {
        if (segashenHod != turn) return;
        for (int k = start; k >= 0; k--)
        {
            if (_turns[k])
            {
                _correct = Array.LastIndexOf(_turns.ToArray(), false);
            }
            else
            {
                _correct = k;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    private static void Show(int start, int end)
    {
        for (int j = start; j <= end; j++)
        {
            if (Holder[j].Image == Deck[j]) continue;
            Holder[j].Image = Deck[j];
            Player.PreviousCall = 0;
            Bot1.PreviousCall = 0;
            Bot2.PreviousCall = 0;
            Bot3.PreviousCall = 0;
            Bot4.PreviousCall = 0;
            Bot5.PreviousCall = 0;
        }
    }

    private async Task Restart()
    {
        PlayedHands1++;
        UpdateStatistics(Folds, PlayedHands1, LostHands, WonHands);
        _winners = 0;
        Call = Bb;
        TempCall = Call;
        Raise = 0;
        Rounds = 0;
        ResetProperties(Player);
        ResetProperties(Bot1);
        ResetProperties(Bot2);
        ResetProperties(Bot3);
        ResetProperties(Bot4);
        ResetProperties(Bot5);
        _restart = false;
        Raising = false;
        _addingChips = false;
        Win.Clear();
        _addWinners.Clear();
        _sorted.Current = (int)Hand.Combinations.Default;
        _sorted.Power = 0d;
        tbPot.Text = @"0";
        _t = 30;
        _up = int.MaxValue;
        _turnCount = 0;
        Bot.PotText = Bb + Sb;
        if (_newTurn < 5)
        {
            _newTurn++;
        }
        else
        {
            _newTurn = 0;
        }
        PickNextBlind();
        RefillChips();
        _imgLocation = Directory.GetFiles(GetCards, "*.png", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        for (int os = 0; os < 17; os++)
        {
            Holder[os].Image = null;
            Holder[os].Invalidate();
            Holder[os].Visible = false;
        }
        dontRepeat = false;
        await Shuffle();
    }
    private static void ResetProperties(UsersProperties user)
    {
        user.Type = (int)Hand.Combinations.Default;
        user.Power = 0;
        user.FoldTurn = false;
        user.Panel.Visible = false;
        user.PreviousCall = 0;
        user.StatusLabel.Text = "";
        GetStatus(user);
    }
    private void RefillChips()
    {
        if (Player.Chips > 0) return;
        var f2 = new AddChips();
        f2.ShowDialog();
        if (f2.A == 0) return;
        Player.Chips = f2.A;
        Bot1.Chips += f2.A / 2;
        Bot2.Chips += f2.A / 2;
        Bot3.Chips += f2.A / 2;
        Bot4.Chips += f2.A / 2;
        Bot5.Chips += f2.A / 2;
        Bb = (int)Player.Chips / 30;
        Sb = Bb / 2;
        Player.FoldTurn = false;
        Player.Turn = true;
        bRaise.Enabled = true;
        bFold.Enabled = true;
        bCheck.Enabled = true;
        bRaise.Text = RepetitiveVariables.Raise;
    }

    private async Task CheckLabels()
    {
        const string fold = @"Fold";
        bool[] conditions =
        {
            StatusLabels[Player.EnumCasted] == fold,
            StatusLabels[Bot1.EnumCasted] == fold,
            StatusLabels[Bot2.EnumCasted] == fold,
            StatusLabels[Bot3.EnumCasted] == fold,
            StatusLabels[Bot4.EnumCasted] == fold,
            StatusLabels[Bot5.EnumCasted] == fold
        };
        var a = StatusLabels.Count(x => x == fold);
        if (a == 5)
        {
            var lastOne = Array.IndexOf(conditions, false);
            var users = new List<UsersProperties> { Player, Bot1, Bot2, Bot3, Bot4, Bot5 };
            foreach (var t in users.Where(t => lastOne == t.EnumCasted))
            {
                t.Panel.Visible = true;
                t.Chips += int.Parse(tbPot.Text);
                MessageBox.Show(t.Name + @" Wins");
                if (t == Player)
                {
                    WonHands++;
                }
                else
                {
                    LostHands++;
                }
            }
            UpdateStatistics(Folds, PlayedHands1, LostHands, WonHands);
            await Restart();
        }
    }
    private async Task CheckTextBoxes()
    {
        const string fold = @"Fold";
        const int zero = 0;
        bool[] conditions =
        {
            Player.Chips != zero && StatusLabels[Player.EnumCasted] != fold,
            Bot1.Chips != zero && StatusLabels[Bot1.EnumCasted] != fold,
            Bot2.Chips != zero && StatusLabels[Bot2.EnumCasted] != fold,
            Bot3.Chips != zero && StatusLabels[Bot3.EnumCasted] != fold,
            Bot4.Chips != zero && StatusLabels[Bot4.EnumCasted] != fold,
            Bot5.Chips != zero && StatusLabels[Bot5.EnumCasted] != fold
        };

        string[] zeroChips =
        {
            ChipsTextBoxes[Player.EnumCasted], ChipsTextBoxes[Bot1.EnumCasted],
            ChipsTextBoxes[Bot2.EnumCasted], ChipsTextBoxes[Bot3.EnumCasted], ChipsTextBoxes[Bot4.EnumCasted],
            ChipsTextBoxes[Bot5.EnumCasted]
        };

        var a = zeroChips.Count(x => x == RepetitiveVariables.ChipsZero);
        var b = StatusLabels.Count(x => x == fold);
        var c = conditions.Count(x => x);
        if (6 - b == a && b != 5 || c == 1 && a > 0)
        {
            _sorted.Current = (int)Hand.Combinations.Default;
            _sorted.Power = 0d;
            Player = (Player)Winner(Player, 1);
            Bot1 = (Bot)Winner(Bot1, 0);
            Bot2 = (Bot)Winner(Bot2, 0);
            Bot3 = (Bot)Winner(Bot3, 0);
            Bot4 = (Bot)Winner(Bot4, 0);
            Bot5 = (Bot)Winner(Bot5, 2);
            await Restart();
        }

    }
    private async Task Flip(int currentTurn)
    {
        bool foldOnFlip = false;
        var a = StatusLabels.Count(x => x == RepetitiveVariables.Fold);
        if (a == 5)
        {
            await CheckLabels();
        }
        else
        {
            int ravno = _turns.Count(c => !c) == 2 ? 0 : 1;
            if (Raising)
            {
                _turnCount = 0;
                Raising = false;

                if (currentTurn == Player.EnumCasted)
                    _correct = Array.LastIndexOf(_turns.ToArray(), false);
                Picking(Bot1.EnumCasted, Player.EnumCasted, currentTurn);
                Picking(Bot2.EnumCasted, Bot1.EnumCasted, currentTurn);
                Picking(Bot3.EnumCasted, Bot2.EnumCasted, currentTurn);
                Picking(Bot4.EnumCasted, Bot3.EnumCasted, currentTurn);
                if (currentTurn == Bot5.EnumCasted)
                    _correct = Array.LastIndexOf(_turns.ToArray(), false, 4, _turns.ToArray().Length - 1);
            }
            else
            {
                if (_turns[_correct])
                    foldOnFlip = true;
                if (_turns.Count(c => !c) == StatusLabels.Count(c1 => c1 == RepetitiveVariables.Check))
                    foldOnFlip = true;
            }
            if (currentTurn == _correct && _turnCount > ravno || foldOnFlip)
            {
                Raise = 0;
                Call = 0;
                _turnCount = 0;
                TempCall = 0;
                Rounds++;
                _correct = currentTurn;

                if (!Player.FoldTurn) StatusLabels[Player.EnumCasted] = "";
                if (!Bot1.FoldTurn) StatusLabels[Bot1.EnumCasted] = "";
                if (!Bot2.FoldTurn) StatusLabels[Bot2.EnumCasted] = "";
                if (!Bot3.FoldTurn) StatusLabels[Bot3.EnumCasted] = "";
                if (!Bot4.FoldTurn) StatusLabels[Bot4.EnumCasted] = "";
                if (!Bot5.FoldTurn) StatusLabels[Bot5.EnumCasted] = "";
                SetStatus(Player);
                SetStatus(Bot1);
                SetStatus(Bot2);
                SetStatus(Bot3);
                SetStatus(Bot4);
                SetStatus(Bot5);
                if (Rounds == Flop)
                {
                    Show((int)TableCards.FirstCard, (int)TableCards.ThirdCard);
                }
                if (Rounds == Turn)
                {
                    Show((int)TableCards.ThirdCard, (int)TableCards.FourthCard);
                }
                if (Rounds == River)
                {
                    Show((int)TableCards.FourthCard, (int)TableCards.FifthCard);
                }
                if (Rounds >= End)
                {
                    Winner(Player, 1);
                    Winner(Bot1, 0);
                    Winner(Bot2, 0);
                    Winner(Bot3, 0);
                    Winner(Bot4, 0);
                    Winner(Bot5, 2);
                    await Restart();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private UsersProperties Winner(UsersProperties inputUser, int options)
    {
        var user = inputUser;
        for (int j = 0; j <= 16; j++)
        {
            if (Holder[j].Visible)
                Holder[j].Image = Deck[j];
        }
        if (options == 1)
        {
            _sorted.Current = (int)Hand.Combinations.Default;
            _sorted.Power = 0d;
            Win.Clear();
            Player = (Player)RemoveFolded(Player);
            Bot1 = (Bot)RemoveFolded(Bot1);
            Bot2 = (Bot)RemoveFolded(Bot2);
            Bot3 = (Bot)RemoveFolded(Bot3);
            Bot4 = (Bot)RemoveFolded(Bot4);
            Bot5 = (Bot)RemoveFolded(Bot5);
        }
        if (user.Type == _sorted.Current && user.Power == _sorted.Power)
        {
            Timer.Enabled = false;
            _winners++;
            user.Panel.Visible = true;
            if (user.Type == (int)Hand.Combinations.HighCard)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(user.Name + CombinationNames[0]);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(user.Name + CombinationNames[user.Type]);
            }
            NewCombinationAchievement(user);
            _addWinners.Add(user.Name);
        }
        if (options != 2) return user;
        Player = (Player)WinnersUpdate(Player);
        Bot1 = (Bot)WinnersUpdate(Bot1);
        Bot2 = (Bot)WinnersUpdate(Bot2);
        Bot3 = (Bot)WinnersUpdate(Bot3);
        Bot4 = (Bot)WinnersUpdate(Bot4);
        Bot5 = (Bot)WinnersUpdate(Bot5);
        return user;
    }
    private UsersProperties WinnersUpdate(UsersProperties user)
    {
        if (!_addWinners.Contains(user.Name)) return user;
        if (user.Name == Player.Name)
        {
            WonHands++;
        }
        else
        {
            LostHands++;
        }
        user.Chips += int.Parse(tbPot.Text) / _winners;
        user.ChipsTextBox.Text = user.Chips.ToString();
        user.Panel.Visible = true;
        UpdateStatistics(Folds, PlayedHands1, LostHands, WonHands);
        return user;
    }

    public void EditSettings()
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.GetStraight = AllAchievements[StraightAchievement.EnumCasted];
        Properties.Settings.Default.GetFlush = AllAchievements[FlushAchievement.EnumCasted];
        Properties.Settings.Default.GetFullHouse = AllAchievements[FullHouseAchievement.EnumCasted];
        Properties.Settings.Default.GetFourOfAKind = AllAchievements[FourOfAKindAchievement.EnumCasted];
        Properties.Settings.Default.GetStraightFlush = AllAchievements[StraightFlushAchievement.EnumCasted];
        Properties.Settings.Default.GetRoyalFlush = AllAchievements[RoyalFlushAchievement.EnumCasted];
    }
    private void NewCombinationAchievement(UsersProperties user)
    {
        if (user != Player || user.Type < (int)Hand.Combinations.Straight) return;
        AllAchievements[user.Type - 4]++;
        Help.UpdateAchievementsList();
        EditSettings();

        if (AchievementRequirements.AchivementList[user.Type - 4].IsUnlocked(AllAchievements[user.Type - 4],
            AchievementRequirements.AchivementList[user.Type - 4].Requirement))
        {
            if (AchievementRequirements.AchivementList[user.Type - 4].Rewards.Item2 != null &&
                AchievementRequirements.AchivementList[user.Type - 4].Rewards.Item2 >
                Properties.Settings.Default.StartingChips)
            {
                var item2 = AchievementRequirements.AchivementList[user.Type - 4].Rewards.Item2;
                if (item2 != null)
                    Properties.Settings.Default.StartingChips =
                        (int)item2;
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
                UnlockedNewAchievement(user.Type - 4);
            }
            else if (AchievementRequirements.AchivementList[user.Type - 4].Rewards.Item2 == null)
            {
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
                UnlockedNewAchievement(user.Type - 4);
            }
        }
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
    private static void NewMoneyAchievement()
    {
        Help.UpdateAchievementsList();
        Properties.Settings.Default.GetMoneyF = AllAchievements[MoneyFirstAchievement.EnumCasted];
        Properties.Settings.Default.GetMoneyS = AllAchievements[MoneySecondAchievement.EnumCasted];

        //smenqne na granicite na fora pri dobavqne na novi parichni achi

        for (int j = MoneyFirstAchievement.EnumCasted; j <= MoneySecondAchievement.EnumCasted; j++)
        {
            if (Player.Chips >= AchievementRequirements.AchivementList[j].Requirement)
            {
                if (AchievementRequirements.AchivementList[j].Rewards.Item2 != null &&
                    AchievementRequirements.AchivementList[j].Rewards.Item2 <
                    Properties.Settings.Default.StartingChips)
                {
                    Properties.Settings.Default.StartingChips =
                        AchievementRequirements.AchivementList[j].Rewards.Item2;
                    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
                    UnlockedNewAchievement(j);
                }
                else if (AchievementRequirements.AchivementList[j].Rewards.Item2 == null)
                {
                    if (Player.Chips != null)
                    {
                        Properties.Settings.Default.GetMoneyF = (int)Player.Chips;
                        Properties.Settings.Default.GetMoneyS = (int)Player.Chips;
                    }
                    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
                    UnlockedNewAchievement(j);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private static void UnlockedNewAchievement(int achiNumber)
    {
        AllAchievements[MoneyFirstAchievement.EnumCasted] = Properties.Settings.Default.GetMoneyF;
        AllAchievements[MoneySecondAchievement.EnumCasted] = Properties.Settings.Default.GetMoneyS;
        AllAchievements[PlayedHandsAchievement.EnumCasted] = Properties.Settings.Default.GetPlayedHands;
        AllAchievements[StraightAchievement.EnumCasted] = Properties.Settings.Default.GetStraight;
        AllAchievements[FlushAchievement.EnumCasted] = Properties.Settings.Default.GetFlush;
        AllAchievements[FullHouseAchievement.EnumCasted] = Properties.Settings.Default.GetFullHouse;
        AllAchievements[FourOfAKindAchievement.EnumCasted] = Properties.Settings.Default.GetFourOfAKind;
        AllAchievements[StraightFlushAchievement.EnumCasted] = Properties.Settings.Default.GetStraightFlush;
        AllAchievements[RoyalFlushAchievement.EnumCasted] = Properties.Settings.Default.GetRoyalFlush;

        if (!AllAchievementsBools[achiNumber])
        {
            AllAchievementsBools[achiNumber] = true;
            Updates.Enabled = false;
            DialogResult dialogResult =
                MessageBox.Show(
                    @"You have unlocked new achievement !" + Environment.NewLine +
                    @"Would You like to check it out ?", @"Achievement", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

            if (dialogResult != DialogResult.Yes) return;
            Timer.Enabled = false;
            Help.UpdateAchievementsList();
            new Help().ShowNewAchievement(AchievementRequirements.AchivementList[achiNumber]);
        }
    }

    private UsersProperties RemoveFolded(UsersProperties user)
    {
        if (user.StatusLabel.Text.Contains(RepetitiveVariables.Fold))
        {
            user.Type = (int)Hand.Combinations.Default;
            user.Power = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            Combinations(user);
        }
        return user;
    }

    private static UsersProperties Ai(Bot user, ref int previous)
    {
        if (!user.FoldTurn)
        {
            if (Rounds == 0)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j < 10; j++)
                {
                    for (int k = 1; k < 10; k++)
                    {
                        if ((_reserve[user.RightCard] / 4 != j || _reserve[user.LeftCard] / 4 != k) &&
                            (_reserve[user.RightCard] / 4 != k || _reserve[user.LeftCard] / 4 != j)) continue;
                        if (Call <= 0)
                        {
                            user = user.Check(user, out previous);
                            goto skip;
                        }
                        if (Call <= user.Chips)
                        {
                            user = user.Call(user, out previous);
                            goto skip;
                        }
                        user = user.Fold(user);
                        goto skip;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (user.Type == (int)Hand.Combinations.HighCard || user.Type == (int)Hand.Combinations.PairTable)
            {
                user.HighCard(user, ref previous);
            }
            if (user.Type == (int)Hand.Combinations.Pair)
            {
                user.PairHand(user, ref previous);
            }
            if (user.Type == (int)Hand.Combinations.TwoPair)
            {
                user.TwoPair(user, ref previous);
            }
            if (user.Type == (int)Hand.Combinations.ThreeOfAKind)
            {
                user.ThreeOfAKind(user, ref previous);
            }
            if (user.Type == (int)Hand.Combinations.Straight)
            {
                user.Straight(user, ref previous);
            }
            if (user.Type == (int)Hand.Combinations.Flush)
            {
                user.Flush(user, ref previous);
            }
            if (user.Type == (int)Hand.Combinations.FullHouse)
            {
                user.FullHouse(user, ref previous);
            }
            if (user.Type == (int)Hand.Combinations.FourOfAKind)
            {
                user.FourOfAKind(user, ref previous);
            }
            if (user.Type == (int)Hand.Combinations.StraightFlush ||
                user.Type == (int)Hand.Combinations.RoyalFlush)
            {
                user.StraightFlush(user, ref previous);
            }
        }
        skip:
        if (user.StatusLabel.Text.Contains(RepetitiveVariables.Fold))
        {
            Holder[user.RightCard].Visible = false;
            Holder[user.LeftCard].Visible = false;
            user.UsernameLabel.Visible = false;
        }
        if (user.Chips <= 0)
        {
            user.FoldTurn = true;
        }
        if (Call < Raise)
        {
            Call = Convert.ToInt32(Raise);
        }
        return user;
    }

    #region User Interface

    private async void timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        _help.Shown += (o, k) =>
        {
            Timer.Enabled = false;
            Updates.Enabled = false;
        };

        if (pbTimer.Value <= 0)
        {
            Player.FoldTurn = true;
            Player.Turn = false;
            pStatus.Text = RepetitiveVariables.Fold;
            Folds++;
            ThinkTime = 0;
            UpdateStatistics(Folds, PlayedHands1, LostHands, WonHands);
            await Turns();
        }
        if (_t > 0)
        {
            _t--;
            pbTimer.Value = _t / 3 * 100;
        }
    }
    private void Update_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        AllAchievements[MoneyFirstAchievement.EnumCasted] = Properties.Settings.Default.GetMoneyF;
        AllAchievements[MoneySecondAchievement.EnumCasted] = Properties.Settings.Default.GetMoneyS;
        AllAchievements[PlayedHandsAchievement.EnumCasted] = Properties.Settings.Default.GetPlayedHands;
        NewMoneyAchievement();

        _help.Shown += (o, k) =>
        {
            Timer.Enabled = false;
            Updates.Enabled = false;
        };

        if (_ifFormLoaded)
        {
            Player = (Player)SetStatus(Player);
            Bot1 = (Bot)SetStatus(Bot1);
            Bot2 = (Bot)SetStatus(Bot2);
            Bot3 = (Bot)SetStatus(Bot3);
            Bot4 = (Bot)SetStatus(Bot4);
            Bot5 = (Bot)SetStatus(Bot5);
        }
        Updates.Enabled = true;
        tbPot.Text = Bot.PotText.ToString();
        if (Player.Chips <= 0)
        {
            tbChips.Text = RepetitiveVariables.ChipsZero;
        }
        if (Bot1.Chips <= 0)
        {
            tbBotChips1.Text = RepetitiveVariables.ChipsZero;
        }
        if (Bot2.Chips <= 0)
        {
            tbBotChips2.Text = RepetitiveVariables.ChipsZero;
        }
        if (Bot3.Chips <= 0)
        {
            tbBotChips3.Text = RepetitiveVariables.ChipsZero;
        }
        if (Bot4.Chips <= 0)
        {
            tbBotChips4.Text = RepetitiveVariables.ChipsZero;
        }
        if (Bot5.Chips <= 0)
        {
            tbBotChips5.Text = RepetitiveVariables.ChipsZero;
        }
        tbChips.Text = RepetitiveVariables.Chips + Player.Chips;
        tbBotChips1.Text = RepetitiveVariables.Chips + Bot1.Chips;
        tbBotChips2.Text = RepetitiveVariables.Chips + Bot2.Chips;
        tbBotChips3.Text = RepetitiveVariables.Chips + Bot3.Chips;
        tbBotChips4.Text = RepetitiveVariables.Chips + Bot4.Chips;
        tbBotChips5.Text = RepetitiveVariables.Chips + Bot5.Chips;
        ChipsTextBoxes[0] = tbChips.Text;
        ChipsTextBoxes[1] = tbBotChips1.Text;
        ChipsTextBoxes[2] = tbBotChips2.Text;
        ChipsTextBoxes[3] = tbBotChips3.Text;
        ChipsTextBoxes[4] = tbBotChips4.Text;
        ChipsTextBoxes[5] = tbBotChips5.Text;
        if (Player.Chips <= 0)
        {
            Player.Turn = false;
            Player.FoldTurn = true;
            SetPlayerStuff(false);
            _t = 0;
        }
        if (_up > 0)
        {
            _up--;
        }
        else
        {
            _up = int.MaxValue;
        }
        if (Player.Chips >= Call)
        {
            bCall.Text = RepetitiveVariables.Call + Call;
        }
        else
        {
            bCall.Text = RepetitiveVariables.AllIn;
            bRaise.Enabled = false;
        }
        if (Call > 0)
        {
            bCheck.Enabled = false;
        }
        if (Call <= 0 && Player.Chips > 0)
        {
            bCheck.Enabled = true;
            bCall.Text = RepetitiveVariables.Call;
            bCall.Enabled = false;
        }
        if (Player.Chips <= 0)
        {
            bRaise.Enabled = false;
        }

        int parsedValue;
        if (tbRaise.Text != "" && int.TryParse(tbRaise.Text, out parsedValue))
        {
            bRaise.Text = Player.Chips <= int.Parse(tbRaise.Text)
                ? RepetitiveVariables.AllIn
                : RepetitiveVariables.Raise;
        }
        if (Player.Chips <= Call)
        {
            bRaise.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    private async void bFold_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pStatus.Text = RepetitiveVariables.Fold;
        Player.Turn = false;
        Player.FoldTurn = true;
        Folds++;
        UpdateStatistics(Folds, PlayedHands1, LostHands, WonHands);
        Player = (Player)GetStatus(Player);
        await Turns();
    }
    private async void bCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Call <= 0)
        {
            Player.Turn = false;
            pStatus.Text = RepetitiveVariables.Check;
        }
        else
        {
            bCheck.Enabled = false;
        }
        Player.PreviousCall = 0;
        Player = (Player)GetStatus(Player);
        await Turns();
    }
    private async void bCall_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Combinations(Player);
        if (Player.Chips >= Call)
        {
            Player.Chips -= Call;
            tbChips.Text = RepetitiveVariables.Chips + Player.Chips;
            tbPot.Text = tbPot.Text != ""
                ? (Bot.PotText = int.Parse(tbPot.Text) + Call).ToString()
                : Call.ToString();
            Player.Turn = false;
            pStatus.Text = RepetitiveVariables.Call + TempCall;
            Player.PreviousCall = Call;
        }
        else if (Player.Chips <= Call && Call > 0)
        {
            if (Player.Chips != null)
            {
                Bot.PotText = int.Parse(tbPot.Text) + (int)Player.Chips;
                pStatus.Text = RepetitiveVariables.AllIn + Player.Chips;
            }
            Player.Chips = 0;
            tbChips.Text = RepetitiveVariables.Chips + Player.Chips;
            Player.Turn = false;
            bFold.Enabled = false;
            Player.PreviousCall = (int)Player.Chips;
        }
        Player = (Player)GetStatus(Player);
        await Turns();
    }
    private async void bRaise_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Combinations(Player);
        int parsedValue;
        if (tbRaise.Text != "" && int.TryParse(tbRaise.Text, out parsedValue))
        {
            if (Player.Chips > Call)
            {
                if (int.Parse(tbRaise.Text) < Bb * 2)
                {
                    tbRaise.Text = (Bb * 2).ToString();
                    MessageBox.Show(@"You must raise atleast twice as the current Big Blind !");
                    return;
                }
                if (Raise > 0 && Raise * 2 > int.Parse(tbRaise.Text))
                {
                    tbRaise.Text = (Raise * 2).ToString();
                    MessageBox.Show(@"You must raise atleast twice as the current raise !");
                    return;
                }
                if (Player.Chips >= int.Parse(tbRaise.Text))
                {
                    Call = int.Parse(tbRaise.Text);
                    TempCall = Call;
                    Raise = int.Parse(tbRaise.Text);
                    pStatus.Text = RepetitiveVariables.Raise + TempCall;
                    Bot.PotText = int.Parse(tbPot.Text) + Call;
                    bCall.Text = RepetitiveVariables.Call;
                    Player.Chips -= int.Parse(tbRaise.Text);
                    Raising = true;
                    Player.PreviousCall = Convert.ToInt32(Raise);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (Player.Chips != null)
                    {
                        Call = (int)Player.Chips;
                        TempCall = Call;
                        Raise = (int)Player.Chips;
                        Bot.PotText = int.Parse(tbPot.Text) + (int)Player.Chips;
                        pStatus.Text = RepetitiveVariables.Raise + TempCall;
                    }
                    Player.Chips = 0;
                    Raising = true;
                    Player.PreviousCall = Convert.ToInt32(Raise);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(RepetitiveVariables.NumberField);
            return;
        }
        Player.Turn = false;
        Player = (Player)GetStatus(Player);
        await Turns();
    }

    public static UsersProperties SetStatus(UsersProperties user)
    {
        user.StatusLabel.Text = StatusLabels[user.EnumCasted];
        user.ChipsTextBox.Text = ChipsTextBoxes[user.EnumCasted];
        return user;
    }
    public static UsersProperties GetStatus(UsersProperties user)
    {
        StatusLabels[user.EnumCasted] = user.StatusLabel.Text;
        ChipsTextBoxes[user.EnumCasted] = user.ChipsTextBox.Text;
        return user;
    }

    #endregion
}
}
```

UserProperties class:

```
namespace Poker.Users
{
    public class UsersProperties : UserControl
    {
        public enum CUser
        {
            Player,
            Bot1,
            Bot2,
            Bot3,
            Bot4,
            Bot5
        }

        public int RightCard { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int? Chips { get; set; }
        public int Type { get; set; }
        public bool Turn { get; set; }
        public bool FoldTurn { get; set; }
        public int PreviousCall { get; set; }
        public int LeftCard { get; set; }
        public double Power { get; set; }
        public int EnumCasted { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Edit** Adding GitHub for the project : https://github.com/tempAccount741/PokerReview

Comment: That's a lot of code, but I'm sure our many C# experts will have plenty of advice for you on improving it. Hope you get some great answers!

Comment: Thanks, @PinCrash There are still some pieces missing but there's just no more place to post it .. i hope you can get some better idea from my other questions which also include some good answers too !

Comment: I dropped the interface tag in favor of [tag:beginner] firstly because interface should probably have been [user-interface] (which is covered under winforms) and additionally [beginner] seems more important

Comment: That was quick. I like the changes you did, but unfortunately you may not incorporate them into your *question* directly. Accordingly  I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*... I strongly suggest you take some time and wait for more answers to come, and then compile your updated code into a **follow-up**-question :)

Comment: Congrats on your first complete app. There's a lot to say about 'done' that a lot of programmers could learn from. Even me.

Comment: Your code is so long it froze my browser for ~10 seconds! :-P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quick glance, going over this from top to bottom:

> ```
>     public enum TableCards
>     {
>         FirstCard = 12,
>         SecondCard = 13,
>         ThirdCard = 14,
>         FourthCard = 15,
>         FifthCard = 16
>     }
> ```

Do the assigned indices have any special meaning?? why are they there? Either add a comment explaining wtf they mean, or shred them. I daresay you don't actually need them...

---

> ```
>     #region Variables
> ```

nope, nope, nope, nope, nope, nope, nope, nope, nope, nope, nope, nope, nope, nope. **THAT** is not the intent of region and using it like that is a **utterly** stupid idea. You're just paving the way for a god-class that does every. single. thing. ever.

That makes your code complex where you should interject abstractions and make code as simple as possible. Regions are just ... meh, mostly.

---

> ```
>     public static RoyalFlush RoyalFlushAchievement = //..
>
>     public static StraightFlush StraightFlushAchievement = //..
>
>     public static FourOfAKind FourOfAKindAchievement = //..
>     public static FullHouse FullHouseAchievement = //..
>     public static Flush FlushAchievement = //..
>     public static Straight StraightAchievement = //..
>     public static MoneyFirst MoneyFirstAchievement = //..
>
>     public static MoneySecond MoneySecondAchievement = //..
>
>     public static PlayedHands PlayedHandsAchievement = //..
> ```

Two things: Your lines are significantly too long, or rather broken up in unuseful places. Also that's probably better off in a class dedicated to handling achievements.

---

> ```
>     public static Bot Bot1 = new Bot(10000, AnchorStyles.Left, "Bot 1", 2, (int)UsersProperties.CUser.Bot1,
>         new Point(15, 420), false, new Tuple<int?, int>(Player.Chips, 6));
>
>     public static Bot Bot2 = new Bot(10000, AnchorStyles.Left, "Bot 2", 4, (int)UsersProperties.CUser.Bot2,
>         new Point(75, 65), true, new Tuple<int?, int>(Player.Chips, 6));
>
>     public static Bot Bot3 = new Bot(10000, AnchorStyles.Left, "Bot 3", 6, (int)UsersProperties.CUser.Bot3,
>         new Point(590, 25), true, new Tuple<int?, int>(Player.Chips, 6));
>     // ...
> ```

Again. Linelength.

Also have you heard of Arrays? Consider using something like:

```
public static Bot[] bots = new Bot[] 
{
    // bot initialization
}
```

Additionally (because I just realize it now) you probably shouldn't make those `public`. Restrict visibilities as much as possible. Every field that's private can't be tampered with. Which means you don't have to worry about it containing some crap you don't want there. That makes it easier to write straightforward code.

Also... Why is everything `static`? Advice from my [latest java answer applies:](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/121719/37660)

> #### Avoid static Like The Plague
>
> Let's get this straight: The ideal object-oriented project has nothing, I repeat NOTHING in static scope,
>   that's data.
>   You should avoid static like the plague, unless you're
>   implementing pure functions (methods without state or side-effects).

---

> ```
>     public static int[] AllAchievements { get; set; } = {
> ```

Achievements Class.. please.

---

> ```
>     public static int AchivementMoney { get; set; }
>     public static int AchivementHands { get; set; }
>     public static int Bb { get; set; } = 500;
>     public static int Sb { get; set; } = 250;
>     public static int Call { get; set; } = 500;
>     public static int Raise { get; set; }
>     public static int Rounds { get; set; }
>     public static int TempCall { get; set; }
>     public int Folds { get; set; }
>     public int WonHands { get; set; }
>     public int LostHands { get; set; }
>     public int PlayedHands1 { get; set; }
> ```

A separate class for keeping score...

---

Okay... Aside from the humungous unused code-block you commented out (and that should be removed, if you don't need it) that's it for your region.

I think if you move all these into specialized classes to separate your concerns, you're busy for a while, so I'll stop here.
It's important to separate responsibilities (what classes do) to make them easy to understand and follow. Why? Because if you have a bug in a laser-focused class it's probably significantly easier to find, than in a mess of ... at least 5 classes that are crammed into one :)

Comment: There are are a lot of static variables because i edit them outside this class and I want to keep they're values over all the other classes too.

Comment: Keeping your values for the entire game is correct. Breaking the code into a hierarchy can help avoid using `static` variables. You may have a `Game` class that has `Players` which in turn have `Hands` etc

Answer (score 1):

some class hierarchy could really go a long way:
consider some of these models:

```
Card
  Suit
  Value 
  Name
Hand
  Collection of 5 Cards
  HandType ("flush", "fullhouse", "nothing")
Player
  Hand
  Chips
Game
  Collection of Players
  Dealer
```